# Laravel 4 weird behavior for variable in IF condition

Tags: php, laravel

Am I doing something wrong?

In Laravel 4 this is not working:

```
$things = DB::table('things')->paginate(20);

if ($things) {
    $view_data = [
        'have_items' => 'yes',
    ];
} else {
    $view_data = [
        'have_items' => 'no',
    ];
}
```

I have to do this:

```
$things = DB::table('things')->paginate(20);

if ($things === true) {
    $view_data = [
        'have_items' => 'yes',
    ];
} else {
    $view_data = [
        'have_items' => 'no',
    ];
}
```

and then it works.

In other frameworks it works like `if ($things)` without any problems.

Can somebody tell me if I am doing something wrong, or is it supposed to work like that?

Comment: if you do a count on $things what do you get?  Is it null?

Comment: If the table is empty 0, else 1 or 2 etc. , depending on the number of rows in that table my code: `$count = count($things); echo $count;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to check the **$things** variable by using **count()** function? Check whether there is value or not. You can check something like this

```
$things = DB::table('things')->paginate(20);

if (count($things)>0) {
    $view_data = [
        'have_items' => 'yes',
    ];
} else {
    $view_data = [
        'have_items' => 'no',
    ];
}
```

hope this will help :) :)

Comment: thanks, I will probably do check like your solution, but it seems a little different from other frameworks, or? How intense is count(0 function? isn't it overkill for an if check?

Comment: Frankly speaking the code you have written obviously the first one seems alright to me.But sometimes its hard to know the problem. actually the syntax is similar to usual syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what causes the problem is that `$things` might not necessarily be null, but it can be an empty array [or collection]. This way it may pass the `if($things)` condition but still contain nothing. That's why you should do additional checks like `if (count($things) > 0)` or even better `if (!empty($things))`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make sure $things is boolean. 
Also try printing the variable $things to see what it brings

Answer (score 0):

`paginate()` will return a `LengthAwarePaginator` which will always evaluate to `true`.  `LengthAwarePaginator` has a method `isEmpty()` you can use so you can do something like the following...

```
$things = DB::table('things')->paginate(20);
$view_data = [
    'have_items' => $things->isEmpty() ? 'no' : 'yes',
];
```